Использовать разные переменные в разных окружениях для тестов
Я новичок в автотестировании с pytest.
Есть проект в котором есть файл data. В data файле есть класс Constants в котором сотня переменных например URL_BASE_API или DB_HOST. Эти переменные используются в тестах.
По мере расширения проекта добавилось второе окружение где необходимо запускать автотесты.
Для запуска автотестов на втором окружении должны использоваться другие значения этих переменных.
Сейчас я каждый раз бегаю в файл data и меняю значения переменных вручную, но хотелось бы создать разные "шаблоны" с переменными, которые бы отличались значением под каждый сервер на котором хочу запустить тесты, и при запуске тестов через командную строку я бы просто флагом выбирал нужный мне шаблон.
Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше это реализовать.
Гугл и ютуб внесли больше вопросов чем ответов.
Спасибо

Можно использовать файлы-конфиги (toml, yaml, или еще что-то). Какой-то из конфигов будет браться по умолчанию, и сделать чтобы можно было при тестах поменять конфиг, который будет использоваться.

Несколько часов гугла - ничего внятного по этому поводу, вобще ничего (( Это какаято вселенская тайна походу

Что именно искали? Модули для работы с toml и yaml легко находятся, дальше реализуете нужную логику.
